# ASP.NET Core Web Optimizer: Not ugly, un minified

Tags: asp.net-core, web-optimization

Is there a way to get the output of my bundles into plain text?

I have played with the appsettings but the files look like they are encoded and or compressed.

```
"webOptimizer": {
 "enableCaching": true,
 "enableMemoryCache": true,
 "enableDiskCache": true,
 "cacheDirectory": "/var/temp/weboptimizercache",
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
{"Headers":{"Last-Modified":"Wed, 02 Mar 2022 19:29:06 GMT","X-Content-Type-   
Options":"nosniff"},"Body":"aHRtbCxib2R5e2hlaWdodDoxMDAlfS5jb250YWluZXItZnVsbHttYXJnaW46M
YWRkaW5nOjE1cHh9I0Zvb3RlciBsaXttYXJnaW46MTBweH0jQ29weXJpZ2h0e3RleHQtYWxpZ246Y...
```

Comment: Do you mean to put the output of this information into something like a txt file?

Comment: Well it is output as a text file in the obj/WebOpimizer folder. but I want to see the css that the less compiler output.  Note the output above does not contain css.